# Pass slightly different procedures as argument

Tags: fortran

I have the following problem:
I have a subroutine called taylorExpansion which accepts a function f of which it computes a first order approximation.

The problem is now that in some cases I want the function f to accept some extra (optional) parameter alpha, but in other cases f doesn't accept this parameter.

```
module myModule
    implicit none
    save

    abstract interface
        subroutine getfunc(x_k,fvalue,alpha) 
            import dp 
            real(kind=dp), dimension(:), intent(in) :: x_k ! 
            real(kind=dp), allocatable, intent(out) :: fvalue(:)
            procedure(num_method), optional :: alpha ! Some functions should be able to accept an extra parameter alpha.
        end subroutine
    end interface

contains
     subroutine taylorExpansion(f)
          procedure(getfunc) :: f
          ...
     end subroutine
end module
```

I want my program to look like the following:

```
program myProgram
     use myModule
     implicit none
     
     call taylorExpansion(func1)
     call taylorExpansion(func2)
contains
     ! This function accepts an extra parameter alpha
     subroutine func1(x_k,fvalue,alpha)
         real(kind=dp), dimension(:), intent(in) :: x_k ! 
         real(kind=dp), allocatable, intent(out) :: fvalue(:)
         procedure(num_method), optional :: alpha
         ...
     end subroutine 
     
     ! This function does NOT accept an extra parameter alpha
     subroutine func2(x_k,fvalue)
         real(kind=dp), dimension(:), intent(in) :: x_k ! 
         real(kind=dp), allocatable, intent(out) :: fvalue(:)
         ...
     end subroutine
end program
```

The problem is now that I can't do this: **Fortran forces me to declare the optional argument alhpa in func2**:

```
     subroutine func1(x_k,fvalue,alpha)
         real(kind=dp), dimension(:), intent(in) :: x_k ! 
         real(kind=dp), allocatable, intent(out) :: fvalue(:)
         procedure(num_method), optional :: alpha
         ...
     end subroutine
```

while this make in reality no sense (func2 never needs a parameter alpha)
Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: It is pretty normal to pass function arguments that have extra arguments they do not actually use to follow the interface requested bu the higher order procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write a wrapper

```
     subroutine func2_wrap(x_k,fvalue,alpha)
         real(kind=dp), dimension(:), intent(in) :: x_k ! 
         real(kind=dp), allocatable, intent(out) :: fvalue(:)
         procedure(num_method), optional :: alpha
         call func2(x_k,fvalue)
     end subroutine
```

and pass this wrapper to `taylorExpansion`.

Comment: This indeed works, but I don't find it particularly elegant. I would like to find another way.

Comment: @john You cannot really change the language.

Comment: @VladimirF Do you have a reference how passed procedure arguments must differ?

Comment: @jack is this comment meant for me? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @jack And I am not sure for what they should differ. I know the requirements for generic resolution, but that is not what we have here, so I am lost.

Comment: @VladimirF I might just create a separate question. Hope I can make myself clearer that way.